# Approximation related to resonance

Tags: analysis, approximation

Can someone help me with this problem.

We have $$x(t)=N \sin (w_{0} t)+\frac{w_0}{w_1}e^{\frac{-t}{T}}\sin (w_{1}t)$$

and $w_1=(1+\frac{\delta_1}{N^2})w_0$ for some $|\delta_1|\leq 1$.

I need to show that 
$$x(t)=N(1-e^{\frac{-t}{T}})\sin (w_0 t)+ \mathrm{O}(1).$$

I obtained $x(t)=N\sin w_0 t+\frac{N^2}{\delta_1+N^2}e^{-\frac{t}{T}}\sin w_1t$ but I don't know how to continue. I think I need to use the fact that $|\sin(a)-\sin(b)|\leq |a-b|$ but I am not exactly sure how to use it here.

Comment: So everything but $t$ is a constant here? And $O(1)$ means bounded when $t$ tends to what? $+\infty$ I guess?

Comment: Yes t is constant and O(1) means bounded when t tends to $+\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's form the difference
$$
x(t)-N\left(1-e^{-t/T} \right)\sin(w_0t)=\frac{w_0}{w_1}e^{-t/T}\sin(w_1t)+Ne^{-t/T}\sin(w_0t).
$$
Now simply use the fact that $|\sin y|\leq 1$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ to get
$$
\left|x(t)-N\left(1-e^{-t/T} \right)\sin(w_0t)\right|\leq\frac{|w_0|}{|w_1|}e^{-t/T}+|N|e^{-t/T}.
$$
The rhs is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and it tends to $0$ as $t$ tends to $+\infty$. So it is bounded and we get the $O(1)$ we want. Actually, we even have $o(1)$.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!